# Google Forms response dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When I searched through Stack Overflow (and the internet) before asking this question, I only found information on making a dashboard of a single form's data, which isn't what I'd like.

I work a lot with Google Forms and I'd love to have a way of knowing how many people have responded to my different active Google Forms. By default, one must open the forms individually to find out.

I'd appreciate any ideas, pointers or existing ressources you know that could help me out : I'd love to avoid builing something *from scratch*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no such existing service which does this. You can however do this in Apps Script with the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) and the [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/).

Valuable pages include [getting all the forms responses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

and [creating charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with multiple forms as well, and I realised that you could maneuver to the "Responses" page. Click on the settings button and select response destination to be an existing spreadsheet, and select a sheet to input your files too. This may be easier although less flexible than coding a script out. Cheers!